# Uploading instant app to Google Play Console fails with generic message

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

I'm working on getting a refactored app up to the pre-release channel in the Google Play console. When I attempt to upload the zip file I get the error "Upload failed. We could not save your changes. Please try again." I've been working on this for many days and feel like I've run out of options to try. Has anyone else experienced this specifically related to instant apps? My app has a base_feature, main_feature, and detail_feature.

I have completed the following:

- The build.gradle files were configured in the same way that Google's sample project is.
- I am attempting to use proguard by setting minifyEnabled to true for each feature module. My proguard rules are configured for each feature and I have no warnings or errors while building.
- Each base + feature APK is under 4MB.
- I have tried uploading in incognito mode as well as another browser without success. I can upload my regular APK (also proguarded) just fine.
- Both the installed APK and the instant app have the same version code/name and bear the same package.

I am at a loss as to what could be causing this error. Typically the console outputs a reason why the upload failed. Is there anything in particular that needs to match between the full uploaded APK and the instant app APK? Hopefully there is a simple solution that I am overlooking. Any help would be very appreciated!

EDIT

base:

```
dependencies {
    api(...)
    api(...)
    api(...)
    api(...)

    feature project(':home')
    feature project(':detail')
    application project(':apk')
}
```

home:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':base')
    api(...)
}
```

detail:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':base')
    api(...)
}
```

instant app:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation project(':home')
    implementation project(':detail')
}
```

apk:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation project(':home')
    implementation project(':detail')
}
```

Comment: Having same issue.

Comment: Seems to be doing it in the development channel as well proguarded or not. I have an APK currently in development but now I can't update it at all.

Comment: At the moment, this message is not well defined. One possible issue has to do with your manifests. Do you have anything in your manifest that references a resource? (some fields may not be allowed) - please show all of your manifests?

Comment: @TWL I can't share the manifests but I have inspected them and made sure to remove almost everything save for the activities and app link urls intent filters. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Try also removing any resource references for any <data> fields (including the app link stuff).

Comment: @TWL The only resource references in any of the manifests are in <activity> or <application> tags i.e app name, launcher icon, etc... Is there a specific naming convention for each feature? Mine are like this com.xxx.xxx.base, com.xxx.xxx.feature.home, com.xxx.xxx.feature.detail and com.xxx.xxx for the application module.

Comment: It shouldn’t have to do with your package names. You previously mentioned “save for ... app link urls intent filters”, so those are hardcoded now, yes? (Another possibility is your dependencies configuration; it is quite an intricate dance now. Can you show your `dependencies{ }` for each gradle file?)

Comment: @TWL Yes, all <data> fields are hard-coded. I have updated my post with `dependencies { }` blocks. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: @TWL I will also add that it seems the issue is something fundamental or build/manifest oriented because if I don't proguard the build I get the same generic error even though my base + feature is over 4MB. In the past I have received an error pertaining to the APK size but this issue is being exposed before that check.

Comment: Ah, this looks similar to Google’s multi-feature-module. In any of your manifests, does AS red-mark any values as “Unresolved class” ? For example (with Google’s sample), the detail’s manifest: `MainActivity` in `android:parentActivityName` is in red, and to fix that: add `implementation project(':main')` to the detail’s gradle.

Comment: @TWL Nothing in my project is red-marked. I was trying to base the structure off of Google's example but it is slightly different. I hadn't actually built their project as I was just following a tutorial and referring back to their project as necessary. I was also referring to willowtreeapps instant app demo along with their tutorial, however there are some differences between how both projects are structured. I was able to load Google's multi-feature module and upload to the dev console without issue. I will start from scratch using Google's project as a template and report back.

Comment: @TWL So I was able to get the build to upload now by moving ALL library dependencies to the base feature. I was trying to keep each feature as small as possible by spreading relevant libraries to their specific module only. Is that not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by moving ALL my external library references (API/implementation) to the base feature. It appears that each feature is not able to host libraries that are only used in that specific feature.

Hopefully there can be an improvement in this area both in the console to better indicate what's wrong with a build but also with the way instant apps are built to better support modularization and reduce APK size.

Comment: When I try to upload Instant app I have same generic message saying 'Upload failed

We could not save your changes. Please try again.' I've put all dependencies in base module, the only dependency that I need to have in feature module is dagger-compiler for dependency injection     annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}")

Don't know what to do/change to be able to upload Instant app to Google Play