# Instant App - Constantly getting error : We could not save your changes. Please try again

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-instant-apps

As per the guidelines provided [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html) i have modularized the existing code. Now i am able to build the signed apk of **installed app** as well as instant app. My installed app got uploaded to playstore without any issue. But while uploading **instant app** apk it is giving me below error.

> We could not save your changes. Please try again.

It is constantly giving me this error & error is not explainable to.Have anyone faced this?

**Screenshot**
[image]

FYI - My app has 3 feature main,base & detail.

Comment: There are other posts about similar issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291749/uploading-instant-app-to-google-play-console-fails-with-generic-message Do you have any library dependencies outside the base feature?

Comment: No i have only attached base library to feature module but i am having webviews in each feature module.

Comment: any comments how this could be solved? I'm having same issue :/

Comment: It is causing due to resources try removing resources string,drawable,styles,etc with hardcoding them whichever gets resolved by id at first try hardcoding app name in manifiest and then try any other things

Comment: @Ragaisis is your issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

With reference to comment @NikhileshPatve

it is causing due to resources try **removing resources string,drawable,styles,etc with hardcoding** them whichever gets resolved by id at first try hardcoding app name in manifiest and then try any other things