# Upload Failed in Google Play Store

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk

[image]

For some reason I'm constanly getting upload failed error in google play when I'm uploading the new apk.

My minsdkversion is 16 and my targetsdkversion is 25

Never had such problems before. I used a webview recently with javascript enabled. Problem persists for more than 10 hrs.

Is the issue on my side or Google's?. Please help. It's emergency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075857/instant-app-constantly-getting-errror-we-could-not-save-your-changes-please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya There is no solution in that post.

Comment: Logout and login again in developer account, then try upload, If not help, try uploading with different browser, firefox.

Comment: Logout and logging back in helped me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick to get around the same error was to explicitly run the 'assemble' Gradle task (or 'assembleFullRelease' in my case) when building the APK to upload.

The APK that was produced by just running the MainActivity was always rejected by Google Play Console even though is was fetched from the same directory (build/outputs/apk/full/release).

Comment: What is assemebleFullRelease? I don't see that option under my gradle tasks.

Comment: Use the 'assemble' Gradle task. That should build all the different builds that you have in your project.