# unable to update published android app apk on google play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I'm trying to update my published android app by uploading another apk from appRelase then edit release but when i upload the apk it says

> couldn't save your changes
>   [image]

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.techno.kashfrohaanyappmahkotf"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075857/instant-app-constantly-getting-error-we-could-not-save-your-changes-please

Comment: i could upload it in the first time and i just changed the xml code by adding new style and changed the version code to 2 and version name to 2.0

Comment: is there current problem for google causing this issue now someone tell me if noticed